# Quasar - This dependency was not found: d.ts

Tags: typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

I have a Quasar app, with TypeScript.

In file, `src/test1.ts`

```js
export enum Enum1 {
  Choice1,
  Choice2
}
```

And, in file, `src/@types/test1/index.d.ts`

```js
export enum Enum1 {
  Choice1,
  Choice2
}
```

They are both identical.

In my `Index.vue` file;

When I import this, it works:

```js
import { Enum1 } from "src/test1";
```

But, when I import this, it gives error:

```js
import { Enum1 } from "src/@types/test1";
```

```
This dependency was not found:

* src/@types/test1 in
  ./node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/loader.transform-quasar-imports.js!
  ./node_modules/ts-loader??ref--3-0!
  ./node_modules/@quasar/app/lib/webpack/loader.auto-import-client.js?kebab!
  ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!
  ./src/pages/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=ts&
```

I've tried adding this line into `tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "typeRoots": ["src/@types", "node_modules/@types"]
    ...
  }
}
```

`package.json` is;

```json
{
  "name": "t3",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "A Quasar Framework app",
  "productName": "Quasar App",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"No test specified\" && exit 0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@quasar/extras": "^1.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "quasar": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^7.2.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^8.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@quasar/app": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.17.15"
  }
}
```

```sh
$ tsc -v
Version 4.0.2
```

Comment: "src/@types/test1" Is a folder. Can you check if it's working if you edit your import as "src/@types/test1/index.d.ts" ?

Comment: this [article](https://www.reddit.com/r/typescript/comments/aa9wu1/sharing_interfacesenums_between_dts_files_and_ts/ecqe0ws?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) mentions that don't use enum in `.d.ts`.